# qPCR: do both primers have to contain a GC-clamp in order to be effective?

Tags: pcr, primer

I'm developing software which, among other things, designs primers pairs (forward and reverse) for qPCR. In my research on various properties, I read about GC-clamps and I understand the basics of it I think. There is still something unclear to me.

Do both primers in a pair need to have a GC-clamp in order for it to be effective? Or does one GC-clamp in, let's say the forward primer, just increases specificity, and both primers containing a clam increasing it even more?

Comment: The new question is too Health'y for me to answer. Very nice edits for Health though. Likely others can answer it.

Comment: If we are adding gc clamp in both primers, the sequence should be different or same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have GC-clamps (3' terminal `G/C`) in both primers; this may overall improve the PCR efficiency. However you should take care not to put too many `G/C`s. This may lead to stabilization of primer pairs, leading to formation of primer-dimers. Also see this post: [When designing primers how important is the GC clamp?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/10843/3340)

GC-clamps are not always essential and you should look at other parameters too.

Comment: So, in summary: A clamp in one primer is good for efficiency and clamps in both are better (with the right amount of G/C ofcourse). So I don't need a GC-clamp in both of them. Is this right?

Comment: @TomKral Not strictly necessary but good if you have it in both.